# Javascript function and prototype - basic routing issue through calling methods

Tags: javascript, function, prototype

I'm approaching learning JavaScript from a Ruby background, so I'm having some trouble understanding (and putting this into words) why my code is failing to produce the results I need. I ran this at pythontutor.com to see a step-by-step walkthrough of whats happening, and it confirms my suspicions. However, I'm not sure exactly why this is the case.

I'm building a thermostat, and its supposed to return 'green' once the temperature is below 18dC. On my penultimate line, the console.log is 17 which is correct, however when I call `thermostat.displayColor` on the last line it still says yellow. The code terminates there, and doesn't go back through `this.displayColor = this.currentColor()` which I expect it to (since it did this on the first run to define the starting color as 'yellow'.

The code works correctly and returns 'green' if I change the code to directly call the prototype method `this.currentColor()`, however I just want to know why it's not letting me do it in the way I've written below.

I'm not sure of the terminology to describe this problem, so apologies in advance for my title not being accurate.

```
var DEFAULT_TEMP = 20;

function Thermostat(){
  this.temperature = DEFAULT_TEMP;
  this.maxTemp = 25;
  this.powerMode = 'on';
  this.displayColor = this.currentColor()
};

Thermostat.prototype.downButton = function(){
  if (this.temperature === 10){
    throw new Error('temp cannot be lower than 10dC');
  };
  this.temperature --;
};

Thermostat.prototype.currentColor = function() {
  if ((this.temperature >= 18) && (this.temperature < 25)) {
    return 'yellow'
   } 
    else if (this.temperature < 18) {
   return 'green'
   }

   else {
   return 'red'
   }
};

var thermostat = new Thermostat(); 
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        thermostat.downButton();
      }; 
console.log("spec file test green, temp should be 17 and is:" + thermostat.temperature)
console.log(thermostat.displayColor); //this should be green, but it is yellow!
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should call the `currentColor()` method, `displayColor` is only set in the constructor (at which time temperature is 20) and is not updated when the temperature changes.

It might make sense to add the color setting to the `downButton` method:

```
Thermostat.prototype.downButton = function(){
  if (this.temperature === 10){
    throw new Error('temp cannot be lower than 10dC');
  };
  this.temperature --;
  this.displayColor = this.currentColor();
};
```

Comment: thank you Rob for the quick response! Is there any particular reason as to why the displayColor is only set once (at the point of initialization)? I'd like to read up more about this, its probably a really fundamental concept but I'm not sure how to start looking for this

Comment: @ggwc whenever you create the instance you are calling the constructor function. That is the only time that the `Thermostat()` function is called therefore `displayColor()` is only called once

Comment: @ggwc No problem. Perhaps you are thinking that `this.displayColor = this.currentColor()` will bind the value of `displayColor` in some way that it always calls the `currentColor` function to get its value, but that is not what happens. The constructor (`function Thermostat(){...`) is called one time when you instantiate `new Thermostat()` and the values you set within the constructor are static unless updated by other member functions or externally.

Answer (score 2):

As Rob says, you should call the function that calculates the current color. Here is his suggestion along with some improvements to your code:

```js
function Thermostat() {
  this.MIN_TEMP = 10;
  this.MAX_TEMP = 25;
  this.temperature = 20;
}

Thermostat.prototype.decreaseTemp = function () {
  if (this.temperature > this.MIN_TEMP) this.temperature--;
};
Thermostat.prototype.increaseTemp = function () {
  if (this.temperature < this.MAX_TEMP) this.temperature++;
};
Thermostat.prototype.currentColor = function() {
  if (this.temperature < 18) return 'green';
  if (this.temperature < 25) return 'yellow';
  return 'red';
};

var thermostat = new Thermostat(); 
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  thermostat.decreaseTemp();
}

// no errors mean all assertions pass
thermostat.temperature.should.equal(17);
thermostat.currentColor().should.equal('green');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/should.js/8.2.2/should.min.js"></script>
```